# Print lines between two patterns and sleep for a second then repeat till the EOF

Tags: awk, sed, pattern-matching, sleep

There are many answers to the first part of the question, that is printing lines between two patterns. For example :

```
awk '/start/{flag=1} flag; /end/{flag=0}' file
```

This prints out the lines between the patterns "start" and "end" that occurs several times within the "file". Suppose the file contains :

```
start a b c d 4 5 3 7 8 end some garbage start 6 d 0 0 1 d g end other garbages start 6 5 ... end some other garbage
```

The above "awk" command prints out the whole file eliminating the garbage.. which is fine, but what I want is a pause between each such chunk. That is print

`start a b c d 4 5 3 7 8 end`

sleep for a second (`sleep 1` can be used) then print the next chunk :

```
start 6 d 0 0 1 d g end
```

and so on till the end of the file. I searched extensively but could not find the second "pausing/waiting" part hence I believe this is not a duplicate question.

Comment: Are you sure that awk script is doing what you say it's doing?

Comment: To clarify, it doesn't work for me given your sample data and I can't see how it would work without a for loop to iterate the fields in the record. If a for loop is implemented, then one could, in the test for `/END/` implement a `system("sleep 10")` before the loop kicks on to the next field. But that's a moot point since the script doesn't appear to do what it's supposed to.

Comment: @JNevill actually you are right, it prints out the whole file. But anyway I am not interested in that awk command, that was just an example. What I want I described in the question.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS="[[:space:]]+"; ORS=" " }
/start/ { found=1 }
found   { print }
/end/   { printf "\n"; found=0; system("sleep 1") }

$ time awk -f tst.awk file
start a b c d 4 5 3 7 8 end
start 6 d 0 0 1 d g end
start 6 5 ... end

real    0m3.214s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.122s
```

Note that the variable name should be `found` or a similarly meaningful word, not `flag` as a flag is what type of variable it is, not what it represents. Naming a flag variable `flag` is like naming your integer variables `integer` instead of `count` or `sum` or something else meaningful.

Comment: Hi, it still prints out everything in one go ! I want something that matches these two patterns (start and end) and prints out one such block and pause for a second and then find the next block etc.

Comment: No it doesn't, it does exactly what it is shown to be doing in my answer. If you are having a different experience then your real input doesn't match your posted input or you're not using gawk.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using `system("sleep 1")` as suggested by [EdMorton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45358790/171318) would be to pipe awk's output into a bash `while` loop:

```
awk ... | while read -r line ; do
    echo "${line}"
    sleep 1
done
```

That would avoid to spawn an extra shell for each sleep operation.

Comment: I do not see the patterns "start" and "end" used anywhere, but at least it is printing out single lines so it is useful for me, although I found another  solution very similar to yours:  `#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo "$line"
    sleep 1
done < "$1"` thanks a lot.

Comment: What I meant is, use the awk script from EdMorten, remove the `system("sleep 1")` from it and pipe it to the while loop. But it is just a very little optimization. The answer from EdMorten should work for you.